# Find the height and length of waves in noisy data

Tags: matlab, filtering

My goal is to find the maximum values of wave heights and wave lengths.

`dwcL01` though `dwcL10` is arrays of `<3001x2 double>` with output from a numerical wave model.

Part of my script:

```
%% Plotting results from SWASH
% Examination of phase velocity on deep water with different number of layers
% Wave height 3 meters, wave peroid 8 sec on a depth of 30 meters
clear all; close all; clc;
T=8;
L0=1.56*T^2;

%% Loading results tabels.
load dwcL01.tbl; load dwcL02.tbl; load dwcL03.tbl; load dwcL04.tbl;
load dwcL05.tbl; load dwcL06.tbl; load dwcL07.tbl; load dwcL08.tbl;
load dwcL09.tbl; load dwcL10.tbl;
M(:,:,1) = dwcL01; M(:,:,2) = dwcL02; M(:,:,3) = dwcL03; M(:,:,4) = dwcL04;
M(:,:,5) = dwcL05; M(:,:,6) = dwcL06; M(:,:,7) = dwcL07; M(:,:,8) = dwcL08;
M(:,:,9) = dwcL09; M(:,:,10) = dwcL10;

%% Finding position of wave crest using diff and sign.
for i=1:10
    Tp(:,1,i) = diff(sign(diff([M(1,2,i);M(:,2,i)]))) < 0;
    Wc(:,:,i) = M(Tp,:,i);
    L(:,i) = diff(Wc(:,1,i))
end
```

This works fine for finding the maximum values, if the data is "smooth". The following image shows a section of my data. I get all peaks, when I only need the one around `x = 40`. How do I filter so I only get the "real" wave crests. The solution needs to be general so that it still works if I change the domain size, wave height or wave period.

[image: dwcL02]

Answer (score 1):

If you're basically trying to fit this curve of data to a sine wave, have you considered performing Fourier analysis (FFT in Matlab), then checking the magnitude of that fundamental frequency? The frequency will tell you the wave spacing, and the magnitude the height, and when used over multiple periods will find an average.
See the [Matlab help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) for an example of the usage 
but the basic gist is:

```
y = [...] %vector of wave data points
N=length(y); %Make sure this is an even number
Y = fft(y); %Convert into frequency domain

figure;
plot(y(1:N)); %Plot original wave data
figure;
plot(abs(Y(1:N/2))./N); %Plot only the lower half of frequencies to hide aliasing
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one more solution that might work for you. It involves computing the 2nd-order derivative using a 5-point central difference instead of the 2-point finite differences. When using `diff` twice you are performing two first-order derivatives consecutively (finite 2-point differences) which are very susceptible to noise/oscillations. The advantage of using a higher-order approximation is that the neighboring points help filter out the small oscillations, and this may work for your case.

Let `f(:) = squeeze(M(:,2,i))` be the array of data points, and `h` is the uniform spacing distance between the points:

```
%Better approximation of the 2nd derivative using neighboring points:
for j=3:length(f)-2
    Tp(j,i) = (-f(j-2) + 16*f(j-1) - 30*f(j) + 16*f(j+1) - f(j+2))/(12*h^2);
end
```

Note that since this 2nd-order derivative requires the 2 neighboring points to the left and right, that the range of the loop must start at the 3rd index and end 2 short of the array length.